# undefined on console | jquery | syntax

Tags: jquery

what is my syntax problem with this code??? console says undefined. :(

question is so simple it is syntax problem... I wsnt to learn how to write this code better

```
jQuery(function($){
  $(document).on('change', '.step select', function(){
if ($(this).val() !== '') {
    var CurrentStepVariable = $(this)[name];
    console.log(CurrentStepVariable);
} } ) } );
```

> I ask you that who want process without defination from pc? me?
> oh,no...

Comment: You need to get element name attribute ? if yes try like this : `$(this).attr('name')`

Comment: Can you add the html code of .step select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this kind of code problem, there is our importantly recommadation that is using    `$(this).attr('name')` . So, with following this way, you can solve your problem easly.